# Child element position relative working wrong

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I have a div element of css width and height, 800x600. I am using javascript to generate three object elements in the div that should be in a diagonal line, touching each other. I am using position:relative, and the left and top css properties to position the object elements. However when I do it this way, there is a horizontal gap between the squares that shouldn't be there. When I use positon:fixed, they line up how I want it but not inside the div element.

Html of my div element

```
<div id="Stage" style="background:black;width:800px;height:600px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;overflow:hidden;">
```

and my javascript

```
w="w";
level_data =
[
[w,0,0],
[0,w,0],
[0,0,w],
];

function generate(level_data){
    for(row=0;row<level_data.length;row++){
        for(col=0;col<level_data[row].length;col++){
            posx = col*50; posy=row*50;
            if(level_data[row][col]=="w"){
                entity = document.createElement('object');
                entity.style.position = "relative";
                entity.style.left = String(posx)+"px"; entity.style.top = String(posy)+"px";
                entity.data = "Objects/Sprites/Wall.jpg";
                document.getElementById("Stage").appendChild(entity);

            }
        }
    }
}
generate(level_data);
```

This is what I get: [Link1](http://www.newgrounds.com/dump/draw/67b485d58d6513626af9a41bc53535bb)

This is what I want: [Link2](http://www.newgrounds.com/dump/draw/4a6a4ccd565d188f838b3dc46597c0b6) but the redsquares inside the big black square instead. What's the problem?

Comment: Remember to declare all your variables with `var` otherwise you're leaking to the global space. `row` `col` `entity` `posx` `posy` they all seem to be leaking.

Comment: Try setting the `entity.style.left` values to 0.  Otherwise, it's `left` relative to the entity before it in the DOM.

Comment: Ah thank you Explosion Pills. That's what it was. Anyway I can get it to be relative to parent div, without the object elements pushing each other, rathen that just setting left to 0, because this was just a test, and the actual thing will have gaps in it and it would be easier to just have the elements not push each other, instead of keep track of how many elements are in the row before it to work it out it's position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: fixed` positions elements relative to the viewport. `position: relative` gives that result because `object` element probably has some default value for `widht` and `height`. You'll need something like this:

```
entity.style.position = "absolute";
entity.style.left = String(posx)+"px";
entity.style.top = String(posy)+"px";
entity.style.width = "50px";
entity.style.height = "50px";
```

When using `position: absolute`, the code is supposed to work even without dimensions for the `entity`. Notice , that when using `position: relative` you should not multiply position values with `col`, they should be just `50px`.

Comment: Yeah I've tried setting width, and height, and also using img. I'm using object instead of img because this I'm making an html game and I don't want the sprites to be right clickable. Also using position absolute positions it relative to the page instead of the div. I've found the problem was the elements were pushing each other inside the parent div

Comment: @GregHornby I see... anyway, the point of my answer was to use `position: absolute` instead of `relative`. Did you try that?

Comment: yes I tried that and it gives the same result as position: fixed

Comment: Oh wait. I set the div element to position:fixed, so now the entity with position:absolute works how I want! Thank you